# Notepad++: Is it possible to highlight a sentence within a delimiter?

Tags: notepad++

This is the scenario:
I have | as a delimiter.

The format is like this:

```
John | Doe | 4th Street, Block 7 | +1 | Confirmed | 8745219966
```

Would it be possible that if I double click on the "4th Street, Block 7" that I can highlight 4th until 7?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setings > Preferences > Delimiter

Type `|` as start and end delimiter.

Then keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> pressed and double-click in the zone you want to highlight